# Real Analysis Derivative

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

Consider the function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ where $f$ is defined by
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
x^b\sin(1/x), &\text{if $x>0$};\\
0,&\text{if $x<=0$.}
\end{cases}$$
Prove that the derivative $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ if and only if $b>2$.

Im not exactly sure what to do here, im thinking maybe something with left and right limits?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $b \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1):

See that
if $b = 0$ then f is not even continous. 
if $b=1$ f is continuous but not differentible.
if $b=2$ f is differentiable and derivative is not continuous.
if $b=3$ f has continuous derivatives but the second derivative does not exists.
if $b=4$ f is twice differentiabl but the second derivative is not continuous.
and so on . . .

Answer (score 0):

For $\;x\neq 0\;$:

$$f'(x)=bx^{b-1}\sin\frac1x-x^{b-2}\cos\frac1x$$

For $\;x=0\;$:

$$f'(0)\stackrel?=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^b\sin\frac1x}x=\lim_{x\to 0}x^{b-1}\sin\frac1x=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;b>1\\{}\\\text{doesn't exist}&\,\;\;b\le 1\end{cases}$$

Well, for $\;f'(x)\;$ to be continuous at zero it must be that $\;f'(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}f'(0)=0\;$ . For this to happen **at least** it must be that $\;f'(0)\;$ exists and thus $\;b>1\;$, but also$\;\ldots\ldots$